# Difference between presentational component and container component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components, containers

When should we use presentational component and when should we use container component?

Comment: How smart or dumb is your component?
 https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 2):

- Prensentational components (or dumb components) normally are used on to create some UI they don't care about how the data is loaded or mutated, they don't have any logic inside(if they have is via props), often they are created as functional components unless they need some state or lifecycle methods.
- Containers component (or smart components) They are a charge of carrying data to components (presentational or other containers) instead of passing props down and down. If you are using react-redux every component that you wrap with connect and pass a mapStateToProps function are considered Containers.

Check this post by Dan Abramov, he explains in more detail this topic
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 1):

- Presentational - no state, have no dependencies on the rest of the
  app, handle how things look
- Container - usually has state, call redux actions, handle how things work

Full comparison here: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)